# How to repeat non POT subtexture in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, tiles

We have a texture atlas, which contains not square subtextures, which we would like to use as tile textures to fill our ground in the game. We need to use not square tiles, because of specific shape of levels in our 2d game and the requirement to have many graphic packs for different mobile screens. So it is not convenient to link the size of the ground texture to power of two.

Can't find any working shader or explanation in google. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some information about how you are using these data in the shader would be nice.

What I usually prefer to have is getting the texture coordinates in the shader as if there was no atlas. Then next to that I add a "frame" as to where the sub-texture lies on the actual texture. The repeating must then be done manually in the fragment shader. (The vertex shader is inappropriate as it will only result in stretching the texture).

So basically you need to modify the input coordinates to be in range of `[0,1]` and use those. So if coordinate is for instance `12.12` you need to use it as `.12` or `x=x-(1/x)` for positive and `x=x-((1/x)-1)` for negative.

Take a look at this code (just a concept, I did not test it):

```
    uniform lowp vec4 subtextureRelativeCoordinates;// Represents a part of the texture where the sub texture lies. Origin is .xy, size is .zw
    varying highp vTextureCoordinates;  // actual texture coordinates which you would use if no atlasing was present

    main() {
        // resample texture coordinates to be in range [0,1] as if they need to repeat
        int xCount = (int)(1.0/vTextureCoordinates.x); // might also be negative
        int yCount = (int)(1.0/vTextureCoordinates.y); // might also be negative
        // a negative coordinates will always have +1. For instance -1.5 will return xCount=-1 but the result must be -1.5 - (-1-1) = .5
        xCount += vTextureCoordinates.x<.0?-1:0;
        yCount += vTextureCoordinates.y<.0?-1:0;
        vTextureCoordinates -= vec2(xCount, yCount);

        lowp vec2 textureCoordinate = textureCoordinates*subtextureRelativeCoordinates.zw + subtextureRelativeCoordinates.xy;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! We have already implemented something very similar!